An unexpected way to find an ancient city
The following flags could be translated into the following letters:











M
somewhere in East Asia (5)



J
somewhere in the Middle East (7)



B
somewhere in West Europe (5)



C
somewhere in West Europe (10)



Could you find out which ancient city these flags represent?

Hint

 Although these countries are unknown, we all know the fans whose outfits matches the flags :)


Would you have higher-resolution pictures of these flags?

@DanDan面, at the moment, no. It wouldn't add any extra information. You can always zoom in if you like.

In the first flag, for instance, it is slightly unclear to me whether the central red figure is meant to be a circle or a cross. Although I assume it is supposed to be a circle :)

@DanDan面, doesn't matter very much. Colors are more important than shapes

First of all, let's observe that each row points towards:

 Disney Princesses. The "flag" is a simplified version of their dresses, then the first letter of their names, then a rough location and number of letters in their names. We can fill the table like this:


  | M | somewhere in East Asia (5) = MULAN


  | J | somewhere in the Middle East (7) = JASMINE


  | B | somewhere in West Europe (5) = BELLE


  | C | somewhere in West Europe (10) = CINDERELLA

Then we look at the flags at the bottom:


 S = SNOW WHITE


 P = POCAHONTAS


 A = ARIEL


 R = RAPUNZEL


 T = TIANA


 A = AURORA

Looking at the letters each clue provides we get the ancient city:

 SPARTA


Ah yes, so the last image (the 'double-up') must be rot13(gur qerff sebz gur znxr-vg-cvax-znxr-vg-oyhr fprar). All makes sense now - great spot :)

Correct, well done. Although the first A isnt rot13(nheben), but a different one.

Out of curiosity, which flag did you recognize first?

(FWIW In my comment above I also thought both A's were just alternative 'appearances' for the same one, since 'the other A' is more renowned for a 'different appearance' on first thought...)

@Lezzup I've corrected the first A, I had a hard time distinguishing each. The first flag I recognised was M, then the first one in the answer. I knew I had seen those colors somewhere and there was a key word in the first hint.
